# UserInformations are getting updated

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, user-profile

Whatever changes made on the UserInformtion in AD, it is not getting updated in users Mysite.

Farm Information:
SharePoint 2007 + SP2 + Dec-09 CU.

Issue:
AD-Team changes the user email-id.
changes are getting updated in SSP.
changes are not getting populated from SSP to Mysite/Site-collections.

any thoughts?

Comment: Are you doing a full import or an incremental import?  Have you looked at the import log to see if there are any error messages?

Comment: I ran the Full import job without a success.

Answer (score 0):

could you try running the following:

```
stsadm -o sync
```

Comment: Executed the below commands without success:
Stsadm –o sync –listolddatabases 0 
Stsadm –o sync –deleteolddatabases 0 
Stsadm –o sync
 
Stsadm –o sync –ignoreisactive 1
Stsadm –o sync 

“Moving” field in siteSynch table in SSP DB is set to 1 (true)
Set the value to "0"
Stsadm –o sync 

any clues?